# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in rails 3.2.12 with default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, default-scope

We want to use `default_scope` to be flexible with the columns shown on `customer index` page. For example, if a user should not see customer `phone#`, then we remove `phone` from `default_scope` and want to leave the `phone` blank on `index` page. We got this idea from online and is doing a test. However there is an error `missing attribute:phone` when `phone` is selected. Here is our definition for `default_scope` in `customer` model:

```
def self.default_scope
      Customer.scoped.select("active,name,sales_id,customer_status_category_id, short_name, zone_id, id, since_date")
end
```

The index page:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>ShortName</th>
    <th>SinceDate</th>  
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Active?</th>
    <th>CustomerStatusCategory</th>
    <th>Sales</th>
    <th>LastContactDate</th>

  </tr>

<% @customers.each do |cust| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= cust.id %></td>
    <td><%= cust.short_name %></td>
    <td><%= cust.since_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") %></td>
    <td><%= cust.phone if cust.phone.present? %></td>
    <td><%= cust.active %></td>
    <td><%= cust.customer_status_category.name %></td>
    <td><%= cust.sales.name %></td>    
    <td><%= return_last_contact_date(cust.id).strftime("%Y/%m/%d") %></td> 

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The error is:

```
 ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Customerx/customers#index

Showing C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/customerx/app/views/customerx/customers/_index_partial.html.erb where line #32 raised:

missing attribute: phone
```

Is it possible to show an empty column by purposely not selecting it in `index` (or any view page)? If it is possible, is `default_scope` a right tool to accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that `default_scope` isn't what you need.  isn't it possible to just have an `if` statement to check if the user can see the phone number or not?

Comment: We are currently doing if. The problem with if is that the code has to be changed when a new field needs to be turned on or off. We want to find a way to turn on or off some column(s) without changing the code.

Comment: you can look at presenters/decorators to have a centralized place to filter what you want to show the users.